# Send iOS pushnotifications in JSON format trough Amazon SNS

Tags: php, ios, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

I'm in the works of migrating my own iOS pushservice into Amazon SNS. Previously I was pushing messages trough our own server which no longer is enough.

The backend is built with PHP and this is some code of how I send a pushnotification with the old solution:

```
$body = array(
    'alert' => array('body' => $id,
                   'action-loc-key' => 'read this',
                   'loc-key' => '%@',
                   'loc-args' => array($message)),
    'badge' => '0',
    'sound' => 'default',
    'content-available' => '1'
    );
```

That is the body of the notification I sent. Now I want to get the same notification to be sent trough SNS, with the AWS PHP SDK [publish-method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.Sns.SnsClient.html#_publish).

I've figured out that I have to send the pushnotification trough this:

```
$result = $snsClient->publish(array(
        'TargetArn' => $target,
        // Message is required
        'Message' => $message,
        'MessageStructure' => 'json'
    ));
```

What would $message be, in the codeexample above? All help is appreciated!

Edit: I've successfully sent the pushnotification trough SNS dashboard with the following JSON. My problem is to reproduce this trough the PHP SDK.

{
 "APNS":"{\"aps\":{\"alert\":{\"body\":\"7500\", \"action-loc-key\":\"read this\", \"loc-key\":\"%@\", \"loc-args\":[\"Message\"]}, \"badge\":\"0\", \"sound\":\"default\", \"content-available\":\"1\"} }"
}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem!

The following code did the trick, my previously attempts did not create either a good json-string (notice that there are two json_encodes in there) or didn't have the "default" json key which is required.

```
$message = json_encode(array(
                'default' => $message,
                'APNS' => json_encode(array(
                    'aps' => array(
                        'alert' => array('body' => $id,
                               'action-loc-key' => 'read this',
                               'loc-key' => '%@',
                               'loc-args' => array($message)),
                    ),
                    'badge' => '0',
                    'sound' => 'default',
                    'content-available' => '1'
                ))
            ));

$result = $snsClient->publish(array(
            'TargetArn' => $target,
            'MessageStructure' => 'json',
            'Message' => $message
        ));
```

Comment: Awesome. I'm glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this would work for your purposes, but in the AWS SNS API dashboard to send a single message out the format is like this:

```
{"APNS_SANDBOX": "{\"aps\": {\"alert\":\"HERE IS AN ALERT, BADGE, and SOUND!\",\"badge\": 1,\"sound\":\"bingbong.aiff\"}}"}
```

To send to a topic in the dashboard you use a string like this:

```
{ 
    "default": "HERE IS AN ALERT, BADGE, and SOUND",
    "APNS_SANDBOX": "{\"aps\": {\"alert\":\"HERE IS AN ALERT, BADGE, and SOUND!\",\"badge\": 1,\"sound\":\"bingbong.aiff\"}}"
}
```

The escaped quotes are required when sending from the dashboard.

When sending to production you replace `APNS_SANDBOX` with `APNS`

Comment: Thanks! But my problem is to go from my own backend. I should have mentioned that I've already sent a successful message trough SNS dashboard with the following json:

{
 "APNS":"{\"aps\":{\"alert\":{\"body\":\"7500\", \"action-loc-key\":\"read this\", \"loc-key\":\"%@\", \"loc-args\":[\"Message\"]}, \"badge\":\"0\", \"sound\":\"default\", \"content-available\":\"1\"} }"
}

How do I reproduce this trough the PHP SDK?

Comment: came across this today, good answer but no quotes can be used around badge count or it will not work on current Amazon SNS Dashboard.  Like so { "APNS_SANDBOX":"{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"TEST ALERT, BADGE, and SOUND\", \"badge\":1, \"sound\":\"default\"} }" } will work fine

Answer (score 2):

Going off of GrapplingCoder's answer, here is the JSON for sending a basic push notification with text that uses the default notification sound:

```
{
"APNS": "{\"aps\":{\"alert\": \"This is your message text!\",\"sound\":\"default\"} }"
}
```